# Typecast "340" to int results in '34' losing the last zero

Tags: python, regex

**Scenario1:**

input:  `"1-0:1.7.0(00.471*kW)"`

regex:  `"[0-9]-[0-9]:1.7.0\([0]{1,}(.*)\\*kW\)"`

output: **471** (as it should be)

**Scenario2:**

input:  `"1-0:1.7.0(00.470*kW)"`

regex:  `"[0-9]-[0-9]:1.7.0\([0]{1,}(.*)\\*kW\)"`

output: ***47*** instead of *470*

manipulation:`output = int(str(str(float("{0:.4f}".format(float(re.search("[0-9]-[0-9]:1.7.0\([0]{1,}(.*)\\*kW\)",linestr).group(1))))).replace(".","")).replace("*",""))`

**Question:**
When the input is like Scenario 2, I want the output to be 470 instead of 47. 
 How can I get all characters including trailing zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want the digits after the `.`:

```
s = "1-0:1.7.0(00.471*kW)"
print(int(re.findall(":1.7.0\([0]+\.(\d+)\\*kW\)",s)[0]))
471

s  = "1-0:1.7.0(00.470*kW)"

print(int(re.findall(":1.7.0\([0]+\.(\d+)\\*kW\)",s)[0]))
470
```

Or simply:

```
print(int(re.findall("\([0]+\.(\d+)\\*kW\)",s)[0]))
```

Comment: (int(re.findall(":1.7.0\([0]+\.(\d+)\\*kW\)",linestr)[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: the code works using the input you provided, what does it actually look like?

Comment: You did not copy the code I provided exactly. You did not escape the first paren.. `\([0]`

Comment: I used your regex and I get: = (int(re.findall(":1.7.0\([0]+\.(\d+)\\*kW\)",linestr)[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range with intput 1-0:1.7.0(00.471*kW)

Comment: You still have not used the regex i provided